# this.setState() is not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-redux

I have the following code snippet which renders a D3Tree. D3Tree is React Component and `contextmenu` is **outside** the React. In order to access and set the state of D3Tree, it is **binded** to D3Tree. Now on initial load and on right click and change of state , D3Tree re-renders, but on change of page and re-load of D3Tree Component, it does not re-render on right click and change of state by `contextmenu`(contextmenu is called on right-click in d3  function as `.on('contextmenu',contextmenu)`). Can some one please explain this undesired behavior and what is that to be done. Scroll down for code.
(If I re-load the D3Tree Component and right click on node it is **not** re-rendering even on **state change**)

```
export default class D3Tree extends BaseWidget {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            style_popup : {
                top : 90,
                left : 90,
                position : 'absolute'
            },
            render_on_click : false
        }
        contextmenu = contextmenu.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        var mountNode = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.tree);


        // Render the tree usng d3 after first component mount
        if (this.props.treeData) {
            renderTree(this.props.treeData, mountNode, this.props.nodeName);
        }

    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){

        var mountNode = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.tree);
        // Delegate rendering the tree to a d3 function on prop change
        if (this.props.treeData != nextProps.treeData) {
            renderTree(nextProps.treeData, mountNode, this.props.nodeName);
        }



         return true;
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <div id="tree">
                <div id ="tree-container" ref={(tree) => { this.tree = tree; }}>

                </div>
                {
                (this.state.render_on_click) ? <div><PopUp popup_style = {this.state.style_popup} /></div> : null
                }
          </div>
        );
    }
}




function contextmenu(node)
{

        this.setState({
            style_popup : {
                top : d3.event.clientY,
                left : d3.event.clientX,
                position : 'absolute'
            },
            render_on_click : true
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a self-contained example using eg [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)? You have a couple of bad practises in your snippet above but it isn't sufficient to say where the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

Context menu function is outside of class, put this function inside class and then bind that function into constructor as this.contextmenu = this.contextmenu.bind(this);

Comment: contextmenu is a JS function. It is called inside renderTree() function which is also JS function. I will not able to call contextmenu if I keep it inside React Component . Can I ?

Comment: within a react component you can call contextmenu function.

Comment: How do I call context menu from outside component if it's inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bind like `contextmenu = contextmenu.bind(D3Tree)`.
Either you can call `contextmenu` with `.call` method (which accepts context as first argument)

Comment: Where do I have to bind this. I have already binded in constructor. Isn't that right ?

Comment: your class doesn't know about this function. bind it outside of class

Comment: either you can move it to your class and bind it there